# spritekit didBeginContact not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

didBeginContact doesnt get called for some reason. How can I fix this? Thanks! I set the category bitmasks and the skphysicsContactDelegate, yet it is still not registering contacts. I've been stuck at this for some time now.

```
#import "MyScene.h"
#import "FuelNode.h"
#import "SKSpriteNode+DebugDraw.h"

typedef NS_OPTIONS(uint32_t, CollisionCategory) {
    CollisionCategoryPlayer     = 1 << 0,
    CollisionCategoryFuel       = 1 << 1,
};

@interface MyScene() <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@end

@implementation MyScene

{
    SKNode *_playerNode;
    SKNode *_backgroundNode;
    SKNode *_foreGround;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

        _backgroundNode = [self createBackground];
        [self addChild:_backgroundNode];

        _foreGround = [SKNode node];
        [self addChild:_foreGround];

        //add a fuelNode
        FuelNode *fuel = [self createFuelAtPosition:CGPointMake(160, 440)];
        [_foreGround addChild:fuel];

        _playerNode = [self createPlayer];
        [_foreGround addChild:_playerNode];

        SKAction *actionMove = [SKAction moveToY:-100 duration:3.0];
        [fuel runAction:actionMove];

        NSLog(@"yea");
    }

    return self;
}

-(SKNode *)createPlayer
{
    CGSize playerPhysicsBody;
    //Create player
    SKNode *playerNode = [SKNode node];
    SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"wship-3.png"];
    player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, 120);

    [playerNode addChild:player];

    //Add physics
    playerPhysicsBody = CGSizeMake(player.size.width/2, player.size.height/2);
    playerNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:playerPhysicsBody];
    playerNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    //Setup collision settings
    playerNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    playerNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryPlayer;
    playerNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    playerNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategoryFuel;

    [player attachDebugRectWithSize:playerPhysicsBody];

    return playerNode;
}

-(SKNode *)createBackground
{
    //Create background
    SKNode *bgNode = [SKNode node];
    SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"purple"];
    bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

    [bgNode addChild:bg];
    return bgNode;
}

- (FuelNode *)createFuelAtPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    // 1
    FuelNode *node = [FuelNode node];
    [node setPosition:position];
    [node setName:@"NODE_FUEL"];

    // 2
    SKSpriteNode *sprite;
    sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"fuelBlue"];
    [node addChild:sprite];

    // 3
    CGSize contactSize = CGSizeMake(sprite.size.width/2, sprite.size.height/2);
    node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:contactSize];

    // 4
    node.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    //Setup collision settings
    node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryFuel;
    node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    //node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategoryPlayer;

    [sprite attachDebugRectWithSize:contactSize];

    //SKAction *actionMove = [SKAction moveToY:-100 duration:3.0];
    //[node runAction:actionMove];

    return node;
}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    BOOL fuelCollision = NO;

    SKNode *other = (contact.bodyA.node != _playerNode) ? contact.bodyA.node : contact.bodyB.node;

    NSLog(@"collision");

    fuelCollision = [(GameObjectNode *)other collisionWithPlayer:_playerNode];

}


@end
```

Comment: Fixed! In the create player method I have mistakenly set the position of the player sprite instead of setting the position of the player node!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! In the create player method I have mistakenly set the position of the player sprite instead of setting the position of the player node!

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable contact detection, you need to set

```
node.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/dynamic) as well.

Comment: Actually I tried this beforehand and this doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: You still need the physicsBody to be dynamic. Try setting the contactTestBitMask for the fuel node as well...

Comment: I thought they need to be dynamic for collisions to work. Contact messages should be triggered even if the bodies are not set to be dynamic. Anyway it doesnt matter if I set them to be dynamic or not, one of them or both because it still doesnt trigger the method.